# Banking system using polymorphism

Tags: c++, object-oriented, classes, polymorphism

I am asking this, because after studying I am confused that it is necessary to declare base class object, then declare derived class object and then store reference of derived class object in base class in c++ to use polymorphism.
But what do you think, did I use polymorphism in `Accounts`, `CurrentAccount`, `SavingAccount` and also between `Person`, `Customer`, `Manager` classes or not?

The code runs correctly with no issues, but the concept is confusing.

Accounts.h

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class Accounts
{
public:
    Accounts();
    ~Accounts();
    virtual void WithDraw(int) = 0;
    virtual void Deposit(int, string, int, int) = 0;//Also can be named as add Account
    virtual void Balance() {};
    virtual void DeleteAccount(int)=0;
    virtual int getAccountsNumber()=0;
};
//Definning classes methods
Accounts::Accounts()
{
    cout << "\nThe Accounts class started\n";
    //no need to initialize vectors.They work perfect without initializing.C++ has done work for it
}
Accounts::~Accounts()
{
    cout << "\nThe Accounts class Ended\n";
}
```

CurrentAccount.h

```
#pragma once
#include"Accounts.h"
class CurrentAccount:public Accounts 
{

public:
    CurrentAccount();
    ~CurrentAccount();
    void WithDraw(int);
    void Deposit(int, string, int, int);//Also can be named as add Account
    void Balance();
    void DeleteAccount(int);
    int getAccountsNumber();
protected:
    vector<int> Account_ID_Current;
    vector<string> AccountType_Current;
    vector<int> Customer_ID_Current;
    vector<int> Account_Balance_Current;
};

CurrentAccount::CurrentAccount()
{
    cout << "\nCreate Account Class started";
}

CurrentAccount::~CurrentAccount()
{
    cout << "\nCreate Account Class ENDED";
}

void CurrentAccount::Deposit(int AID, string AT, int CID, int AB)
{
    Account_ID_Current.push_back(AID);
    AccountType_Current.push_back(AT);
    Customer_ID_Current.push_back(CID);
    Account_Balance_Current.push_back(AB);

}
void CurrentAccount::WithDraw(int index)
{
    cout << "\nThe Account ID of " << (index + 1) << " person is equal to: "
        << Account_ID_Current[index] << endl;

    cout << "\nThe Account Type of " << (index + 1) << " person is equal to: "
        << AccountType_Current[index] << endl;

    cout << "\nThe Customer ID of " << (index + 1) << " person is equal to: "
        << Customer_ID_Current[index] << endl;

    cout << "\nThe Account Balance of " << (index + 1) << " person is equal to: "
        << Account_Balance_Current[index] << endl;

}
void CurrentAccount::DeleteAccount(int index)
{
    Account_ID_Current.erase(Account_ID_Current.begin() + index);
    AccountType_Current.erase(AccountType_Current.begin() + index);
    Customer_ID_Current.erase(Customer_ID_Current.begin() + index);
    Account_Balance_Current.erase(Account_Balance_Current.begin() + index);
    //Displaying that the account is successfully removed from the bank
    cout << "\nThe Account ID of " << (index + 1) << " was successfully removed from the bank";
    cout << "\nThe Account Type of " << (index + 1) << " was successfully removed from the bank";
    cout << "\nThe Customer ID of " << (index + 1) << " was successfully removed from the bank";
    cout << "\nThe Account Balance of " << (index + 1) << " was successfully removed from the bank";

}
//It will display all the balance in the bank
void CurrentAccount::Balance()
{
    //The static int is not changed on the iteration where ever used in the loop or where ever
    static int sum = 0;//To store the sum of all balance
    for (int i = 0; i < Account_ID_Current.size(); i++)
    {
        sum = sum + Account_Balance_Current[i];
    }
    cout << "\nThe total balance in the bank in the current account is equal to : " << sum;
}
int CurrentAccount::getAccountsNumber()
{
    return Account_ID_Current.size();
}
```

SavingAccount

```
#pragma once
#include"Accounts.h"
class SavingAccount :public Accounts
{

public:
    SavingAccount();
    ~SavingAccount();
    void WithDraw(int);
    void Deposit(int, string, int, int);//Also can be named as add Account
    void Balance();
    void DeleteAccount(int);
    int getAccountsNumber();
protected:
    vector<int> Account_ID_Saving;
    vector<string> AccountType_Saving;
    vector<int> Customer_ID_Saving;
    vector<int> Account_Balance_Saving;
};

SavingAccount::SavingAccount()
{
    cout << "\nSaving Account Class started";
}

SavingAccount::~SavingAccount()
{
    cout << "\nSaving Account Class ENDED";
}

void SavingAccount::Deposit(int AID, string AT, int CID, int AB)
{
    Account_ID_Saving.push_back(AID);
    AccountType_Saving.push_back(AT);
    Customer_ID_Saving.push_back(CID);
    Account_Balance_Saving.push_back(AB);
}
void SavingAccount::WithDraw(int index)
{
    cout << "\nThe Account ID of " << (index + 1) << " person is equal to: "
        << Account_ID_Saving[index] << endl;

    cout << "\nThe Account Type of " << (index + 1) << " person is equal to: "
        << AccountType_Saving[index] << endl;

    cout << "\nThe Customer ID of " << (index + 1) << " person is equal to: "
        << Customer_ID_Saving[index] << endl;

    cout << "\nThe Account Balance of " << (index + 1) << " person is equal to: "
        << Account_Balance_Saving[index] << endl;

}
void SavingAccount::DeleteAccount(int index)
{
    Account_ID_Saving.erase(Account_ID_Saving.begin() + index);
    AccountType_Saving.erase(AccountType_Saving.begin() + index);
    Customer_ID_Saving.erase(Customer_ID_Saving.begin() + index);
    Account_Balance_Saving.erase(Account_Balance_Saving.begin() + index);
    //Displaying that the account is successfully removed from the bank
    cout << "\nThe Account ID of " << (index + 1) << " was successfully removed from the bank";
    cout << "\nThe Account Type of " << (index + 1) << " was successfully removed from the bank";
    cout << "\nThe Customer ID of " << (index + 1) << " was successfully removed from the bank";
    cout << "\nThe Account Balance of " << (index + 1) << " was successfully removed from the bank";

}
//It will display all the balance in the bank
void SavingAccount::Balance()
{
    //The static int is not changed on the iteration where ever used in the loop or where ever
    static int sum = 0;//To store the sum of all balance
    for (int i = 0; i < Account_ID_Saving.size(); i++)
    {
        sum = sum + Account_Balance_Saving[i];
    }
    cout << "\nThe total balance in the bank is equal to : " << sum;
}
int SavingAccount::getAccountsNumber()
{
    return Account_ID_Saving.size();
}
```

Bank.h

```
#include"Accounts.h"
#include"CurrentAccount.h"
#include"SavingAccount.h"
#include"Customer.h"
#include"Manager.h"
using namespace std;
class Bank
{
    Customer customers;
    CurrentAccount accountsC;
    SavingAccount accountsS;
public:
    Bank();
    ~Bank();
    //Methods for current accounts
    void Add_Current_Account(int, string, int, int);
    int Get_Current_NoOfAccounts();
    void Delete_Current_Account(int);
    void getAll_current_Balance();
    //Methods for current accounts


    //Methods for saving accounts
    void Add_Saving_Account(int, string, int, int);
    int Get_Saving_NoOfAccounts();
    void Delete_Saving_Account(int);
    void getAll_saving_Balance();
    //Methods for saving accounts



    void AddCustomer(string, int);
    void DeleteCustomer(int);

    string GetCustomer_Name(int);
    void driverProgram();
};
Bank::Bank()
{
   
    cout << "\nThe program is in the bank class\n";
}

//Current Account
void Bank::Add_Current_Account(int AID, string AT, int CID, int AB)
{
    accountsC.Deposit(AID, AT, CID, AB);
}
void Bank::Delete_Current_Account(int index)
{
    accountsC.DeleteAccount(index);
}
int Bank::Get_Current_NoOfAccounts()
{
    int num = accountsC.getAccountsNumber();
    return num;
}
void Bank::getAll_current_Balance()
{
    accountsC.Balance();
}
//Current Account

//Saving Account
void Bank::getAll_saving_Balance()
{
    accountsS.Balance();
}
void Bank::Add_Saving_Account(int AID, string AT, int CID, int AB)
{
    accountsS.Deposit(AID, AT, CID, AB);
}
void Bank::Delete_Saving_Account(int index)
{
    accountsS.DeleteAccount(index);
}
int Bank::Get_Saving_NoOfAccounts()
{
    int num = accountsS.getAccountsNumber();
    return num;
}
//Saving Account


void Bank::AddCustomer(string name, int ID)
{
    customers.AddCustomer(name, ID);
}
void Bank::DeleteCustomer(int index)
{
    customers.DeleteCustomer(index);
}

string Bank::GetCustomer_Name(int index)
{
    string name = customers.getCustomerName(index);
    return name;
}
void Bank::driverProgram()
{
    Manager m1;
   

    //For Polymorphism and using virtual functions pointers or refrences one is necessary to use otherwise
 //we cannot use virtual functions and polymorphism
    Accounts* currentAccount;
    currentAccount = new CurrentAccount();
    //I am declaring current account pointer

    //Declaring Saving Account
    Accounts* savingAccount;
    savingAccount = new SavingAccount();
    //Declaring Saving Account


    Bank b1;

    char options;

    cout << "\n\nEnter what you want to do \n1 for entering the managers data,\n2 for showing the managers data "
        << "\n3 for adding a customer in the bank\n4 for adding an Account in the bank \n5 for deleting the customer\n"
        << "\n6 for deleting the Account\n7 for getting customer name\n8 for getting the No. of Accounts"
        << "\n9 for seeing all the balance in the bank\nPress 'e' for exit";

    cin >> options;


    switch (options)
    {
    case '1':
    {
        string name;
        string branch;
        int id;
        //The manager class data
        cout << "\nEnter the Data of managers Class: \n";
        cout << "\nEnter the name of manager: \t";
        cin >> name;
        cout << "\nEnter the branch of manager: \t";
        cin >> branch;
        cout << "\nEnter the Id of manager: \t";
        cin >> id;
        m1.TakeManagersData(name, branch, id);
        break;
    }
    case '2':
    {
        cout << "\nThe data of Manager is : ";
        m1.Print_ManagerDetails();
        break;
    }
    case '3':
    {
        string Cname;
        int CID;
        cout << "\nEnter the name of customer: ";
        cin >> Cname;
        cout << "\nEnter the Customer ID: ";
        cin >> CID;
        b1.AddCustomer(Cname, CID);

        break;
    }
    case '4':
    {
        char optionB;
        cout << "There are two options available for creating account.\nOne is saving account(INTEREST)\t"
            << "Press '1' for it and \nSecond one is Current Account(NO INTEREST)\tPress '2' for it\n";
        cin >> optionB;
        int AID;
        int CID;
        int AB;
        string AT;

        switch (optionB)
        {
        case '1':
        {
            cout << "\nEnter the Account ID: ";
            cin >> AID;
            cout << "\nEnter the Customer ID: ";
            cin >> CID;
            cout << "\nEnter the Account BALANCE: ";
            cin >> AB;
            cout << "\nEnter the Account Type: ";
            cin >> AT;

            b1.Add_Saving_Account(AID, AT, CID, AB);
            cout << "\nSuccessfully created a Saving account\tBut delete it as soon as possible\n";
            break;
        }
        case'2':
        {
            cout << "\nEnter the Account ID: ";
            cin >> AID;
            cout << "\nEnter the Customer ID: ";
            cin >> CID;
            cout << "\nEnter the Account BALANCE: ";
            cin >> AB;
            cout << "\nEnter the Account Type: ";
            cin >> AT;

            b1.Add_Current_Account(AID, AT, CID, AB);
            cout << "\nSuccessfully created a Current account\nKeep It as long as you want\n";
            break;
        }
        default:
            cout << "\nSorry Try Again!\nEnter right value only one or two\n";
            break;
        }


        break;
    }
    case '5':
    {
        int index;
        cout << "\nEnter the customer which you want to delete: ";
        cin >> index;
        b1.DeleteCustomer(index);

        break;
    }
    case '6':
    {
        char optionB;
        cout << "There are two options available for DELETING account.\nOne is saving account(INTEREST)\t"
            << "Press '1' for it and \nSecond one is Current Account(NO INTEREST)\tPress '2' for it\n";
        cin >> optionB;

        int index;

        switch (optionB)
        {
        case '1':
        {
            cout << "\nEnter the account number you want to delete\n";
            cin >> index;

            b1.Delete_Saving_Account(index);
            cout << "\nSuccessfully deleted Saving account at the given address\n";
            break;
        }
        case'2':
        {
            cout << "\nEnter the account number you want to delete\n";
            cin >> index;

            b1.Delete_Current_Account(index);
            cout << "\nSuccessfully deleted a Current account at current index\n";
            break;
        }
        default:
            cout << "\nSorry Try Again!\nEnter right value only one or two\n";
            break;
        }



        break;
    }
    case '7':
    {
        int cn;
        cout << "\nEnter the customer ID which you want to get name: ";
        cin >> cn;
        b1.GetCustomer_Name(cn);

        break;
    }
    case '8':
    {
        char optionB;
        cout << "There are two options available for getting number of account.\nOne is saving account(INTEREST)\t"
            << "Press '1' for it and \nSecond one is Current Account(NO INTEREST)\tPress '2' for it\n";
        cin >> optionB;

        switch (optionB)
        {
        case '1':
        {
     
            cout << "\nThe number of accounts of Saving account type are: \t" << b1.Get_Saving_NoOfAccounts() << endl;
            break;
        }
        case'2':
        {
            cout << "\nThe number of accounts of Current account type are: \t" << b1.Get_Current_NoOfAccounts() << endl;
            break;
        }
        default:
            cout << "\nSorry Try Again!\nEnter right value only one or two\n";
            break;
        }


        break;
    }
    case '9':
    {
        char optionB;
        cout << "There are two options available for getting the balance in the bank.\nOne is saving account(INTEREST)\t"
            << "Press '1' for it and \nSecond one is Current Account(NO INTEREST)\tPress '2' for it\n";
        cin >> optionB;

        switch (optionB)
        {
        case '1':
        {

            cout << "\nThe Balance of Saving account type is: \t" << endl;
            b1.getAll_saving_Balance();
            break;
        }
        case'2':
        {
            cout << "\nThe Balance of Current account type is: \t" << endl;
            b1.getAll_current_Balance();
            break;
        }
        default:
            cout << "\nSorry Try Again!\nEnter right value only one or two\n";
            break;
        }


        break;
    }
    case 'e':
    {
        cout << "The program is ending now: ";

        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        cout << "\n\nEnter right value please: \n";
    }
    delete currentAccount;
    delete savingAccount;
    currentAccount = nullptr;
    savingAccount = nullptr;
    }
}

Bank::~Bank()
{
    cout << "\nThe Bank class ended \n";
   
}
```

Customer.h

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include"Person.h"
using namespace std;
class Customer:protected Person
{
public:
    Customer();
    void AddCustomer(string, int);
    void PrintAllCustomersData();
    void DeleteCustomer(int);
    void Print_CustomerDetails(int);
    string getCustomerName(int);
};
Customer::Customer()
{
    cout << "\nThe customer class started\n";
}
void Customer::AddCustomer(string n, int id)
{
    Name.push_back(n);
    ID.push_back(id);
    cout << "\nThe customer " << n << "with Id: " << id << " was successfully added in the Bank.";
}
void Customer::PrintAllCustomersData()
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ID.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "\nThe ID of " << (i + 1) << "Customer is : " << ID[i] << " and NAME is : " << Name[i];
    }
}
void Customer::DeleteCustomer(int index)
{
    Name.erase(Name.begin() + index);
    ID.erase(ID.begin() + index);
    cout << "\nThe customer with Name : " << Name[index] << " and ID: " << ID[index] << " was successfully deleted\n";
}
void Customer::Print_CustomerDetails(int index)
{
    cout << "The Customer Name is : " << Name[index] << endl;
    cout << "The Id of Customer is : " << ID[index] << endl;
}
string Customer::getCustomerName(int index)
{
    return (Name[index]);
}
```

Manager.h

```
#pragma once
#include"Person.h"
class Manager:protected Person
{

public:
    void Print_ManagerDetails();
    void TakeManagersData(string, string, int);
};
void Manager::Print_ManagerDetails()
{
    cout << "\nName.size: " << Name.size();
    cout << "\nID.size: " << ID.size();
    cout << "\nBranch.size: " << Branch.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < Name.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "\nThe ID of Manager is : " << ID[i] << endl;
        cout << "\nThe Name of Manager is : " << Name[i] << endl;
        cout << "\nThe Branch of Manager is : " << Branch[i] << endl;
    }
}
void Manager::TakeManagersData(string n, string b, int id)
{
    Name.push_back(n);
    Branch.push_back(b);
    ID.push_back(id);
}
```

Person.h

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Person
{
protected:  
    vector<string> Name;
    vector<int> ID;
    vector<string> Branch;

public:
    Person();
    ~Person();
    
};

Person::Person()
{
    cout << "\nPerson class started\n";
}

Person::~Person()
{
    cout << "\nPerson class ENDED\n";
}
```

Source.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include"Bank.h"
#include"Customer.h"
#include"Manager.h"
#include"Accounts.h"

#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Manager m1;

    //For Polymorphism and using virtual functions pointers or refrences one is necessary to use otherwise
    //we cannot use virtual functions and polymorphism
 
    //I am declaring current account pointer

    //Declaring Saving Account
 
    //Declaring Saving Account

    Bank b1;


    bool check = true;
    while (check == true)
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// 

        char options;

       
        cout << "\n\nEnter what you want to do \n1 for entering the managers data,\n2 for showing the managers data "
            << "\n3 for adding a customer in the bank\n4 for adding an Account in the bank \n5 for deleting the customer\n"
            << "\n6 for deleting the Account\n7 for getting customer name\n8 for getting the No. of Accounts"
            << "\n9 for seeing all the balance in the bank\nPress 'e' for exit";


        cin >> options;


        switch (options)
        {
        case '1':
        {
            string name;
            string branch;
            int id;
            //The manager class data
            cout << "\nEnter the Data of managers Class: \n";
            cout << "\nEnter the name of manager: \t";
            cin >> name;
            cout << "\nEnter the branch of manager: \t";
            cin >> branch;
            cout << "\nEnter the Id of manager: \t";
            cin >> id;
            m1.TakeManagersData(name, branch, id);
            break;
        }
        case '2':
        {
            cout << "\nThe data of Manager is : ";
            m1.Print_ManagerDetails();
            break;
        }
        case '3':
        {
            string Cname;
            int CID;
            cout << "\nEnter the name of customer: ";
            cin >> Cname;
            cout << "\nEnter the Customer ID: ";
            cin >> CID;
            b1.AddCustomer(Cname, CID);

            break;
        }
        case '4':
        {
            char optionB;
            cout << "There are two options available for creating account.\nOne is saving account(INTEREST)\t"
                << "Press '1' for it and \nSecond one is Current Account(NO INTEREST)\tPress '2' for it\n";
            cin >> optionB;
            int AID;
            int CID;
            int AB;
            string AT;
        
            switch (optionB)
            {
            case '1':
            {
                cout << "\nEnter the Account ID: ";
                cin >> AID;
                cout << "\nEnter the Customer ID: ";
                cin >> CID;
                cout << "\nEnter the Account BALANCE: ";
                cin >> AB;
                cout << "\nEnter the Account Type: ";
                cin >> AT;

                b1.Add_Saving_Account(AID, AT, CID, AB);
                cout << "\nSuccessfully created a Saving account\tBut delete it as soon as possible\n";
                break;
            }
            case'2':
            {
                cout << "\nEnter the Account ID: ";
                cin >> AID;
                cout << "\nEnter the Customer ID: ";
                cin >> CID;
                cout << "\nEnter the Account BALANCE: ";
                cin >> AB;
                cout << "\nEnter the Account Type: ";
                cin >> AT;

                b1.Add_Current_Account(AID, AT, CID, AB);
                cout << "\nSuccessfully created a Current account\nKeep It as long as you want\n";
                break;
            }
            default:
                cout << "\nSorry Try Again!\nEnter right value only one or two\n";
                break;
            }

            break;
        }
        case '5':
        {
            int index;
            cout << "\nEnter the customer which you want to delete: ";
            cin >> index;
            b1.DeleteCustomer(index);

            break;
        }
        case '6':
        {
            char optionB;
            cout << "There are two options available for DELETING account.\nOne is saving account(INTEREST)\t"
                << "Press '1' for it and \nSecond one is Current Account(NO INTEREST)\tPress '2' for it\n";
            cin >> optionB;

            int index;

            switch (optionB)
            {
            case '1':
            {
                cout << "\nEnter the account number you want to delete\n";
                cin >> index;

                b1.Delete_Saving_Account(index);
                cout << "\nSuccessfully deleted Saving account at the given address\n";
                break;
            }
            case'2':
            {
                cout << "\nEnter the account number you want to delete\n";
                cin >> index;

                b1.Delete_Current_Account(index);
                cout << "\nSuccessfully deleted a Current account at current index\n";
                break;
            }
            default:
                cout << "\nSorry Try Again!\nEnter right value only one or two\n";
                break;
            }



            break;
        }
        case '7':
        {
            int cn;
            cout << "\nEnter the customer ID which you want to get name: ";
            cin >> cn;
            b1.GetCustomer_Name(cn);

            break;
        }
        case '8':
        {
            char optionB;
            cout << "There are two options available for getting number of account.\nOne is saving account(INTEREST)\t"
                << "Press '1' for it and \nSecond one is Current Account(NO INTEREST)\tPress '2' for it\n";
            cin >> optionB;

            switch (optionB)
            {
            case '1':
            {

                cout << "\nThe number of accounts of Saving account type are: \t" << b1.Get_Saving_NoOfAccounts() << endl;
                break;
            }
            case'2':
            {
                cout << "\nThe number of accounts of Current account type are: \t" << b1.Get_Current_NoOfAccounts() << endl;
                break;
            }
            default:
                cout << "\nSorry Try Again!\nEnter right value only one or two\n";
                break;
            }

            break;
        }
        case '9':
        {
            char optionB;
            cout << "There are two options available for getting the balance in the bank.\nOne is saving account(INTEREST)\t"
                << "Press '1' for it and \nSecond one is Current Account(NO INTEREST)\tPress '2' for it\n";
            cin >> optionB;

            switch (optionB)
            {
            case '1':
            {

                cout << "\nThe Balance of Saving account type is: \t" << endl;
                b1.getAll_saving_Balance();
                break;
            }
            case'2':
            {
                cout << "\nThe Balance of Current account type is: \t" << endl;
                b1.getAll_current_Balance();
                break;
            }
            default:
                cout << "\nSorry Try Again!\nEnter right value only one or two\n";
                break;
            }

            break;
        }
        case 'e':
        {
            cout << "The program is ending now: ";

            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            cout << "\n\nEnter right value please: \n";
        }

        }
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>

        char option;

        cout << "Enter y for opening menu again and n for exiting\t";
        cin >> option;
        while (option != 'y' && option != 'n')
        {
            cout << "Enter right value Please! only y or n: ";
            char option1;
            cin >> option1;
            if (option1 == 'y' || option1 == 'n')
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (option == 'y')
        {
            check = true;
        }
        else if (option == 'n')
        {
            check = false;
            cout << "The program is ending now! ";
        }
    }
}
```

The link to view code on github is
https://github.com/Muhammad-Bilal-7896/Program-Bank-With-Inheritance-and-Polymorphism

Comment: Technically it's obvious you are using polymorphsm (your `Accounts` class is abstract and has pure virtual functions). Can you elaborate about your doubs please?

Comment: @πάντα Yes my doubts are that if I will remove virtual keyword from base classes than the same program works .i.e making function normal from pure virtual does not changes anything then where goes the polymorphism

Comment: Well, then you never call these functions through a reference or pointer to the `Accounts` class, otherwise it wouldn't work. Given that, you don't use polymorphism at all (neither static, nor dynamic).

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ then clearing my doubt I think that for using polymorphism it is necessary to use refrence or pointer

Comment: _"I think that for using polymorphism it is necessary to use refrence or pointer "_ To the base class, yes.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ thank you I just wanted to learn about that your conversation was quite helpful.Its cleared now

Comment: See https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56363/casting-base-to-derived-class-according-to-a-type-flag/56380#56380 for how polymorphism works in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But what do you think, did I use polymorphism in `Accounts`, `CurrentAccount`, `SavingAccount` and also between `Person`, `Customer`, `Manager` classes or not?

No, you didn't use polymorphism anywhere in your program. You only work with concrete classes of `CurrentAccount`, `SavingAccount`, `Customer` and `Manager`.

Polymorphism means, that you call the concrete classes functions via a reference or pointer to their base class. E.g.:

```
class Bank
{
    Customer customers;
    Accounts* accountsC;
    Accounts* accountsS;
    // ...
};

Bank::Bank()
{
    accountsC = new CurrentAccount();
    accountsS = new SavingAccount();
    cout << "\nThe program is in the bank class\n";
}
//Current Account
void Bank::Add_Current_Account(int AID, string AT, int CID, int AB)
{
    accountsC->Deposit(AID, AT, CID, AB);
}

// ...
Bank::~Bank()
{
    delete accountsC;
    delete accountsS;
    cout << "\nThe Bank class ended \n";
   
}
```

---

Also the whole program structure and class hierarchy seems a bit suspect to me:

- Shouldn't a `Bank` instance have many `CustomerAccount`s?
- A `Customer` instance could have more than one account at the same `Bank`, no?
- What's the actual role of a `Manager` instance? Could they do something to manipulate a `Customer`s accounts?
- I don't fully understand what `accountsS` (`SavingAccount`) is for. Are you sure that you need it at all?

Comment: I tried to make polymorphism between them just for learning purpose for clearing the concept there was really no need for that in reality.I did this for my learning.

Comment: A customer can have as many accounts in the bank for this vectors are used because they actually grow as the accounts grow dynamically.

Comment: @BilalMohib You should rather have something like `std::vector<Customer>`  and `std::vector<Account*>` inside the `Bank` class, than managing vectors of the properties inside of these classes.

Comment: yaa good suggestion